# Is there any way stopSharingAppFromCenterStage via Teamsjs-sdk. we share the APP from Sidepanel to CenterStage but not vice-versa?

Tags: microsoft-teams-js, msteams-react-base-component

I am working on a Microsoft Teams app where we share an app from the side panel to Center Stage using the Teams JavaScript SDK. While I've successfully implemented the feature to share the app to Center Stage, I am now looking for a way to stop sharing the app from Center Stage back to the side panel.

Is there a way to programmatically stop sharing an app from Center Stage to the side panel using the Teams JavaScript SDK or any other methods?

I have tried using the microsoftTeams.meeting.shareAppContentToStage method from the Teams JavaScript SDK to share the app content to Center Stage in Microsoft Teams meetings. It worked perfectly for sharing from the side panel to Center Stage. However, I am looking for a way to stop sharing the app from Center Stage back to the side panel.

I reviewed the documentation for the Microsoft Teams JavaScript SDK, but I couldn't find a specific method for stopping sharing from Center Stage.

Is there a method or approach in the SDK or any other suggestions to achieve this behavior?